# Is it ok to have negative coefficients in approximation band of the wavelet transform of an image?

Tags: wavelet

I am trying to decompose an image using various wavelets ,Daubechies,Coif,symlet,ortho of all orders. Except db1(Haar), others produce some negative coefficients in approximation band. My understanding is approximation band contains the average values of the original image and hence should contain only positive values. Does it also depend on filter coefficients used for decomposition? I implemented decomposition using dwt2 command as well as using circular convolution with filter coefficients. Both produce same results for higher order wavelet filters.
I want to extract features from wavelet coefficients,negative coefficients may result in wrong feature values hence want to clarify.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approximation band also depends on filter coefficients used for decomposition. More precisely, this situation is completely valid for low-pass decomposition filters having negative coefficients. If you require only positive coefficients in the approximation band, use one of these wavelets in MATLAB: `rbio1.x`, `rbio2.x`, `rbio3.x`.